# OpenGL Adobe conflict on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, adobe

I have a simple OpenGL program for particle dynamics. When compiled on OSX 10.6.8, the program exits with the following when the keyboard handler is invoked.

*2012-06-16 07:30:28.110 xel2d.out[2846:903] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
xel2d.out: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
Started*

Why the hell is Adobe even coming into the picture? The same code compiles and runs fine on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a configuration problem on your machine.  Simply trash (or at least move aside) `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax`.

It's a scripting addition, as you might have guessed. I guess you're loading some framework which is then attempting to load scripting additions. This particular scripting addition can't be loaded because it's not the same architecture. I suspect your program is 64-bit and the scripting addition is 32-bit-only.

I don't know where Adobe Unit Types.osax comes from. A web search may tell you. Or if, having moved it aside, something breaks, then you'll have an idea of what it's required for.

Comment: The bigger question is either how long has that file been there or why is adobe shipping libs that aren't fat?

Comment: Well, actually, it *is* fat. The error says "no matching architecture in *universal* wrapper" (my emphasis). So, even more scary, is that it probably means i386 and **ppc**!

Comment: Yeah well then my first question holds... How long has that file been there... The op could run the file command on it to find out the arch